# Является ли здесь "вообще" вводным словом?

Tags: пунктуация

Вообще(,) только став взрослой, я поняла, как тонко и ненавязчиво отец приучал нас все время что-то делать. Нужна ли запятая?

Answer (score 1):

"Вообще" редко употребляется в функции вводного, в значении "я так считаю", "вообще говоря".

У вас нужно обособить деепричастный оборот, поэтому запятая обязательна в любом случае.

Но все же сравним:

*Вообще, я поняла, как тонко и ненавязчиво отец приучал нас все время что-то делать, только став взрослой* (вообще говоря, я так считаю).

*Вообще я поняла, как тонко и ненавязчиво отец приучал нас все время что-то делать, только став взрослой* (в целом, в общем, обобщая).

То есть в данном случае, если убрать деепричастный оборот, возможны 2 варианта.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: Вообще, только став взрослой, я поняла, как тонко и ненавязчиво отец приучал нас все время что-то делать.

Убрать деепричастный оборот нельзя: нарушится смысл и структура предложения.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

У наречия  «вообще»  два основных значении:  А) всегда или обычно, Б) обобщенно, в целом, в основном. Обычно структура предложения такова, что не требуется его обособление.

Наречие вообще  является вводным словом  и обособляется при наличии следующих условий:

а) это значение  "обобщенно, в целом, в основном", при этом возможна замена выражением «вообще говоря».

б) Структура предложения допускает его обособление (часто "вообще" стоит в начале предложения).

ПРИМЕРЫ

Вообще, всем сказкам на фестивале не хватало лёгкости, полёта фантазии Вообще, одинаковых работ за 12 лет нашего существования не было. Изнутри сарай не запирался, и, вообще, все эти сараи напоминают картонные ящики.

Comment: Т.е. здесь "вообще" является вводным словом, т.к. можно его заменить на "вообще говоря" - я правильно поняла? Или здесь дело в деепричастном обороте? И еще насчет примера: мне почему-то хочется заменить запятые на тире: и вообще - все эти сараи напоминают картонные ящики.

Comment: >> Изнутри сарай не запирался, и(,)??? вообще, все эти сараи напоминают картонные ящики.

Да никогда в жизни. Это с чего? Изымите "вообще" – что получится?

Comment: Niemand, я знала, то Вы будете возражать, поэтому намеренно не указала автора. На самом деле, все вопросы к В. Короленко.

Comment: Alenka, замена на "вообще говоря" очень помогает, в этом случае проверяется и смысл, и структура предложения. Тире было бы авторским знаком, надо весь текст читать, чтоб его обосновать. В этом случае такое масштабное обобщение получается.

Comment: Как по мне, "вообще говоря" - очень туманный критерий. Похож на "обобщая", но при значении "обобщая" запятая не ставится. "Словарь вводных слов" предлагает как проверочное для вводности "я так считаю", а о "вообще говоря" и не вспоминает.

Comment: А вот словарь-справочник  "Трудные случаи русской пунктуации" 2012 года не только вспоминает, но и прямо утверждает, что "вообще" и "вообще говоря" - это одно и то же. Да это и без словаря ясно по простой логике вещей.

Comment: Да не такая уж простая логика. Это "говоря" можно добавить к чему угодно. Ср.: "Человеку вообще незачем сидеть на краю обрыва" - "Человеку, вообще говоря, незачем сидеть на краю обрыва". "Вообще же я всегда был один" - "Вообще же говоря, я всегда был один". Я не знаю ни одного профессионального корректора, который разобрался бы с этим "вообще говоря". Что уж говорить о других.

Comment: Человек вообще (=никогда) не должен так поступать. Человек, вообще говоря, не должен так поступать (оценочное суждение для всех подобных случаев). Семантика и структурный анализ Вам в помощь. "Что уж говорить о других" - вы кого-нибудь конкретно имеете в виду или это относится ко всему сообществу некорректоров, в том числе на данном форуме?

Comment: Это относится к нормальным людям, которым свойственно задавать вопросы.

Comment: >> На самом деле, все вопросы к В. Короленко

Нет, к вам, это же вы такой пример привели. Если мы будем правила постановки тире иллюстрировать Горьким, что получится? Здесь то же самое.

Answer (score 0):

Да, является, если оно в значении "вообще-то".

Да, перепутал. Не "вообще-то", а "вообще говоря".

Comment: "На самом деле, все вопросы к В. Короленко". Вы опять не угадали, я цитирую справочник "Трудные случаи русской пунктуации", а справочник цитирует Короленко. Так что все вопросы к справочнику или к Короленко, но только не ко мне. Вообще (говоря), жизнь учит нас не выступать на открытое пространство без надежного прикрытия в тылу. Очень полезная привычка.

Answer (score 0):

Однако на [Грамма.ру](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Byandsearch%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=416.JyEKST99kc1b-dfG07r2ud7hNQs3g5BRUzemGBX9hEQq8GqpzUvAjX5G2yppsIjy7F5ooe2W7-JJhidtJSyNtQ.5568520efd85799acfa8c05b620be6d23ecee33b&uuid=&state=AiuY0DBWFJ4ePaEse6rgeAjgs2pI3DW99KUdgowt9Xu2OK3FawXhsm5LyVOUy4y8DBBy3AZ8jQBmvOMOLYXzf_2mayqxO4o8guzoPT4Kzg7C96mDTGCv2inbw86wHeGDGQxQLxI1QC47BPd6QIX7Tv4lEbfcBj48Kpit901UyMt9qUmIf_QPGLr-yPg-5c_lbQ8mMe-S9lDj1FkM5AEcHQ&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1LdmtxclhUVzM1eE1wbjBzNDlldVFOaC0zMzZ0Y1pJZ1llMUFWaTZDMGRaakFGWjZ6MHZpQmJ6dFhhbkNQbjZPSEZHX2pXaWdhUnpYNUF1T0JQazF3d1FjeDU3WUJTbDRYdzlybTFzeGExU3ZBbXY&b64e=2&sign=a729b9d44b94eff7cf282c5c5070e0e9&keyno=0&l10n=ru&cts=1408004858851&mc=3.8610523492544297)  и этом сайте [Запятание трудных слов и выражений](http://konorama.ru/igry/zapatan/)слово "вообще" является и наречием и вводным словом.